# ¿Cómo selecciono todas las columnas de una tabla pero a algunas columnas darles formato?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, datatable

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos **MYSQL** con 3 campos "**fecha ultimo pago**", "**monto ultimo pago**" y "**total mas consumo**" de los cuales los campos de "**monto ultimo pago**" y "**total mas consumo**" tiene configuración DECIMAL(9,2) (en esos campos pues es manejo de tipo de dato FLOAT para guardado de información de saldos monetarios).

Ahora bien con una sentencia **SELECT * FROM tabla_pagos** se puede seleccionar toda la tabla pero necesito que los campos "**monto ultimo pago**" y "**total mas consumo**" se formateen con **FORMAT(nombre_columna, 2)** para que al momento de previsualizar en búfer esos campos me los muestre con coma (,) en caso de que sea por ejemplo 6789.56 (en lugar de 0.00) quede como 6,789.56

Requiero mostrar esos datos en una pantalla de una web app, la otra manera que pienso es darle el formato con el estatuto "echo" de PHP al mostrar la data en pantalla, por ejemplo "**echo FORMAT(row[mont_ult_pag], 2)**"

Estoy pensando con algo así como sentencias SELEC anidadas...

*¿Sí me explique? En caso de que no para corregir mi pregunta ¡Una disculpa!, sé que es muy diferente el como almacenar el dato a como mostrarlo en búfer o en pantalla.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:

```
SELECT fech_ult_pag,FORMAT(mont_ult_pag, 2) AS montoultimopago, FORMAT(tot_mas_cons, 2) AS totalmasconsumo
  FROM tabla_pagos
```

Comment: Pero en caso de que tenga 10 columnas, 5 de ellas las necesito formatear y 5 de ellas no lo necesito, pero no quiero mandar a llamar columna por columna ¿Hay alguna manera?

Comment: En ese caso puedes hacer esto:
SELECT *, FORMAT(mont_ult_pag, 2) AS montoultimopago, FORMAT(tot_mas_cons, 2) AS totalmasconsumo FROM tabla_pagos

Comment: ¡Oh, funciona! Pero las columnas me las agrega al final y no me las quita las originales antes de formatear por el * en la sentencia ¿Alguna manera solucionar eso? En todo caso sería seleccionar columna por columna ¡Sigo Googleando un poco!

Comment: No olvides explicar cómo funciona la consulta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.